# Using QDEF in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to update a local table in an Access database using a value passed from a click event. I want to add checkmarks to a column in the table for all the same values as the record that was clicked. What am I doing wrong with the QDEF?

```
Public Sub addcheckmarks(functionLocation As String)
 Dim strsql As String
 Dim qdef As QueryDef

 strsql = "PARAMETERS [CheckLocation] String; UPDATE tbl_TMP_inventory set addlocation = -1 where Location = [CheckLocation]"
 Set qdef = CurrentDb.createQueryDefs("", strsql)
 qdef!CheckLocation = functionLocation
 qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello there! Can you add some details to your question? Are you receiving an error message?

Comment: Can you tell us what happens when you run the code you've posted here? Do you get unexpected results? An error?

Comment: It's `CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef`, not `CreateQueryDefs`.

Comment: Thanks Andre for pointing out the syntax error, strange that VBA didnt flag it as an error. That was all it was. Works great now, can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to build a temporary query for a simple update:

```vb
Public Sub addcheckmarks(functionLocation As String)

    Dim strsql As String
 
    strsql = "UPDATE tbl_TMP_inventory SET addlocation = True WHERE Location = '" & functionLocation & "'"
    CurrentDb.Execute strsql
 
End Sub
```